How to write modifies clauses to avoid unnecessary 'unchanged' postconditions?
I am working on a Dafny project where instances of a class can modify the fields of other objects stored in lists within that class.
In many cases, methods only change a specific attribute of these objects. I would like to know how to specify which attribute is changed in the modifies clause. Is there a way to do this in Dafny?
Here is a simple example:
class A {
  var x : int
  var y : int
}
class B
{
  const l : seq<A>
  method m()
      modifies l
      // I would like to write e.g. modifies (set x`a | a in l)
      ensures forall a :: a in l ==> a.x == 10
      // the following postcondition should be subsumed by the modifies clause
      ensures forall a :: a in l ==>  unchanged(a`y)
  {
     var it := 0;
     while it < |l|
      // here, I would like to write l[it]`x for example
          invariant 0 <= it <= |l|
          invariant forall a :: a in l[..it] ==> a.x == 10
          invariant forall a :: a in l ==> unchanged(a`y)
      {
          l[it].x := 10;
          it := it + 1;
      }
  }
}


The issue with this example is that reads expects a set of objects and not primitives. As it stands your method verifies and we can use it to run tests.
class A {
    var x : int 
    var y : int
    constructor (x : int, y : int) 
        ensures this.x == x
        ensures this.y == y
    {
      this.x := x;
      this.y := y;
    }
  }
  class B 
  {
    const l : seq<A>
    constructor (l : seq<A>)
        ensures this.l == l
    {
      this.l := l;
    }

    method m()
        //modifies l
        modifies (set a | a in l :: a)
        // I would like to write e.g. modifies (set x`a | a in l)
        ensures forall a :: a in l ==> a.x == 10
        // the following postcondition should be subsumed by the modifies clause
        ensures forall a :: a in l ==>  unchanged(a`y)
    {
       var it := 0;
       while it < |l|
        // here, I would like to write l[it]`x for example
            invariant 0 <= it <= |l|
            invariant forall a :: a in l[..it] ==> a.x == 10
            invariant forall a :: a in l ==> unchanged(a`y)
        {
            assert l[it] in l;
            l[it].x := 10;
            it := it + 1;
        }
    }
  }
  method Test() {
    var a := new A(x := 0, y := 0);
    var b := new A(x := 0, y := 2);
    var c := new B([a, b]);
    c.m();
    assert a.x == 10;
    assert b.x == 10;
    assert a.y == 0;
    assert b.y == 2;
   }

However, the set of x's are just a set of primitive values.
With another level of indirection you can get the behavior you would like.
  class BoxedInt {
      var val : int;
      constructor (x : int)
          ensures this.val == x
      {
          this.val := x;
      }
  }

  class BoxedA {
    var x : BoxedInt
    var y : BoxedInt
    constructor (x : BoxedInt, y : BoxedInt)
        ensures this.x == x
        ensures this.y == y
    {
      this.x := x;
      this.y := y;
    }
  }
  class BoxyB {
    const l: seq<BoxedA>
    constructor (l : seq<BoxedA>)
        ensures this.l == l
    {
      this.l := l;
    }

    method m()
        //modifies l
        modifies (set a | a in l :: a.x)
        // I would like to write e.g. modifies (set x`a | a in l)
        ensures forall a :: a in l ==> a.x.val == 10
        // the following postcondition should be subsumed by the modifies clause
        // ensures forall a :: a in l ==>  unchanged(a`y)
    {
       var it := 0;
       while it < |l|
        // here, I would like to write l[it]`x for example
            invariant 0 <= it <= |l|
            invariant forall a :: a in l[..it] ==> a.x.val == 10
            invariant forall a :: a in l ==> unchanged(a`y)
        {
            assert l[it] in l;
            l[it].x.val := 10;
            it := it + 1;
        }
    }
  }
   method BoxedTest() {
    var a := new BoxedInt(0);
    var b := new BoxedInt(2);
    var ba := new BoxedA(a, b);
    var c := new BoxyB([ba]);
    c.m();
    assert ba.x.val == 10;
    assert ba.y.val == 2;
   }

Edit: I think with out changing the definition of A there is no way around specifying what remains unchanged in A. The dynamic frame system requires knowing what all pieces of memory are changing or not. It doesn't make assumptions for anything not specified, and therefore won't verify anything about those memory slots either.
You can make it a little tidier, more convenient though.
  class B 
  {
    const l : seq<A>
    constructor (l : seq<A>)
        ensures this.l == l
    {
      this.l := l;
    }

    twostate predicate unchangedY()
        reads this, l
    {
        forall a :: a in l ==> unchanged(a`y)
    }

    method m()
        modifies l
        ensures forall a :: a in l ==> a.x == 10
        ensures unchangedY()
    {
       var it := 0;
       while it < |l|
            invariant 0 <= it <= |l|
            invariant forall a :: a in l[..it] ==> a.x == 10
            invariant unchangedY()
        {
            assert l[it] in l;
            l[it].x := 10;
            it := it + 1;
        }
    }
  }


Thanks for the suggestion. However, I would like to avoid introducing new object types as you suggested, as this would complicate quite a lot the definition of the representation set for the classes I am working with.

Updated with another example

I verified a version of the Sieve of Eratosthenes which you might find helpful for verifying things with frames. Mostly as an example of twostate predicates and lemmas.

If a method only modifies one attribute of a set A of objects, the correct syntax to express this is 'modifies A`attribute'.
Here the correct solution is the following:
class A {
    var x : int 
    var y : int

  }

  class B 
  {
    const l : seq<A>

    method m()
        modifies (set a | a in l)`x
        ensures forall a :: a in l ==> a.x == 10
        ensures forall a :: a in l ==>  unchanged(a`y)
    {
       var it := 0;
       while it < |l|
            invariant 0 <= it <= |l|
            invariant forall a :: a in l[..it] ==> a.x == 10
        {
            l[it].x := 10;
            it := it + 1;
        }
    }
  }


Code samples are fine, but please also include an explanation of how this is the solution.
